# Getting 403 error while accessing pubs/sub

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm getting below error when i'm trying to access google pubsub via python library.

> HttpError 403 when requesting
>   https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects/xxxx/timeSeries?filter=metric.type%3D%22pubsub.googleapis.com%2Fsubscription%2Fnum_undelivered_messages%22+AND+resource.label.subscription_id%3Dtest&interval.endTime=2018-08-28T13%3A11%3A58.256545Z&alt=json&interval.startTime=2018-08-28T13%3A10%3A58.256533Z returned "The caller does not have permission"

Below is the scenario which i'm trying:

- I'm trying to fetch "number of undelivered messages"  from the subscriber.
- I'm using python library to access the google cloud.
- I'm using to secret json file to access the google.
- I created a service account called "monitoring" and gave monitoring admin, pubsub admin roles, monitoring read roles.
- I have given below scopes for the authorization.

  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.read
- By this script I can get topics list but when I try to fetch monitoring details it is throwing error.

Can somebody help me what I'm missing here?

Comment: The question says "access google pubsub" but it looks like you're making a  ListTimeSeries request to the Monitoring API (monitoring.googleapis.com). Could you clarify?

Comment: Im making call to monitoring.googleapis.com. I’m getting error while extracting the metrics.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same access issues.  Your account needs access to the role "Monitoring Viewer".